# Azure PowerShell - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to automate EventHub creation using Azure PowerShell. I am following the documentation outlined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-powershell-how-to-provision/) and have installed the Azure PowerShell module (v 1.0.3).

I have added the Microsoft ServiceBus library (v3.0)  using the following

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
$dllPath = "$scriptPath\..\..\packages\WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.3.1.2\lib\net45-full\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll"
Add-Type -Path $dllPath
```

But as soon as I try and use the `Get-AzureSBNamespace` command, e.g.

```
$CurrentNamespace = Get-AzureSBNamespace -Name $Namespace
```

I get the following error

```
Get-AzureSBNamespace : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

the same is true of `New-AzureSBNamespace`. I have also tried logging into Azure within the same session using `Login-AzureRmAccount`, but get the same object null reference exception.

Is this a bug, or am i missing something not outlined in the documentation?

Comment: Am I suppose to jump through some other security loop holes? e.g. SSL certificates etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it uses the Service Management API and not the Resource Manager API. For me I ran:

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

And then *Get-AzureSBNamespace* and other SB cmdlets started working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PS 5.0 give this a try: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx)

Comment: Thnx, but still no joy. Followed all the steps described in the link you provided, but on attempting the cmdlet `Get-AzureRmSubscriptions` i get the error `The term 'Get-AzureRmSubscriptions' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. Not finding these cmdlets very helpful.